# actionTab text in lowerCase

Tags: android

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Personal Info").setTabListener(tabListener));
```

I have created action tabs like this but text is appearing in uppercase. How to show it in lowercase.

Comment: you have to apply styles to your tab layout. And in your tab style declare the text size or disable the text Caps.